# preg replace to remove bbcode quote

Tags: regex, preg-replace, quotes

Could someone give me an example of how to I can remove

```
[QUOTE=author;3095231]
```

Author being the authors name, and 3095231 being the post.

I want to use preg replace, or anything similar but not sure how and was wondering for an example, I believe it would be something like [QUOTE=(.+?)]
and i don't know the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex looks almost right to me, you must escape the brackets though.

Assuming it's in PHP, the corresponding code would look like

```
$text = preg_replace('/\[QUOTE=(.+?)\]/', '', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you're looking for is

```
s/\[QUOTE=[^\]]+\]//
```